# Managing multiple TinyMCE editors on a Vaadin page

Tags: tinymce, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a page with multiple TinyMCE editors (org.vaadin.tinymce.TinyMce), and I want to know which the user is 'in'. One approach would be to use the focus/blur events, but I've tried adding a class like this:

```
public class MyTinyMce extends TinyMce implements Focusable<TinyMce> { ... }
```

and then associating event handlers like this:

```
myTinyMce.addFocusListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("focus!!");
});
myTinyMce.addBlurListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("blurred!!");
});
```

but the events don't fire reliably. If I do the exact same thing with a Text component, it works as expected.

I say not "reliably" because they *do* fire if I click on the empty space in the TinyMCE toolbar (to the right of 'Tools' in the screenshot), but not if I click on the TinyMCE menu or into the editable body.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3caP.png)

Am I doing something wrong, or does the TinyMCE component simply not support this use-case? Is there another way to keep track of the user switching between different editors?

Comment: (My first question on here: please forgive any etiquette breaches.)